# Is it possible to edit numberOfLines of UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to edit numberOfLines of UITableViewCell when click on that cell?
possible?

example

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

when selected at cell

cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
```

thanks for all reply

Answer (score 0):

You still have the issue of the cell row height not being able to dynamically resize
because it is set at the time of cell creation. (via heightForRowAtIndexPath)

Oddly enough if you want to determine the size for the text in that text label the best way to do it is with NSString's sizeWithFont.

Comment: You can change the cell height "dynamically" by reloading the row.

Comment: Not without reloading all of the rows with reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to set the frame of label
CGRect rect=cell.textLabel.frame;
rect.size.height=(5*rect.size.height);
cell.textLabel.frame=rect;